# melt with chron

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt, chron

I'm trying to melt a data frame with chron class

```
library(chron)
x = data.frame(Index = as.chron(c(15657.00,15657.17)), Var1 = c(1,2), Var2 = c(9,8))
x
                Index Var1 Var2
1 (11/13/12 00:00:00)    1    9
2 (11/13/12 04:04:48)    2    8

y = melt(x,id.vars="Index")
Error in data.frame(ids, variable, value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 4
```

I can trick with `as.numeric()` as follows:

```
x$Index= as.numeric(x$Index)
y = melt(x,id.vars="Index")
y$Index = as.chron(y$Index)
y
                Index variable value
1 (11/13/12 00:00:00)     Var1     1
2 (11/13/12 04:04:48)     Var1     2
3 (11/13/12 00:00:00)     Var2     9
4 (11/13/12 04:04:48)     Var2     8
```

But can it be simpler ? (I want to keep the chron class)

Comment: Why not simply create the data.frame without `as.chron` and then do: `transform(melt(x, "Index"), Index = as.chron(Index))`?

Comment: I get `Error in strptime(x, format, tz = tz) : invalid 'x' argument` when trying to reconstruct your data.frame.

Comment: @Ista, I've fixed the errors in the input data. Try again.

Comment: What is the problem with your solution? Maube I miss somethin, but you keep the chron class in your final result.

Comment: the problem is that I want to reduce the amount of computation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) I assume you issued this command before running the code shown:

```
library(reshape2)
```

In that case you could use the reshape package instead.  It doesn't result in this problem:

```
library(reshape)
```

Other solutions are to

(2) use R's `reshape` function:

```
reshape(direction = "long", data = x, varying = list(2:3), v.names = "Var")
```

(3) or convert the chron column to numeric, use `melt` from the reshape2 package and then convert back:

```
library(reshape2)
xt <- transform(x, Index = as.numeric(Index))
transform(melt(xt, id = 1), Index = chron(Index))
```

ADDED additional solutions.

Comment: Yes i'm working with reshape2 (and ggplot2, which depend on it).Your solution is practical and work... but it takes much time (a factor of ~10)

Comment: thank, the second solution fits to my purpose. 3rd solution short correction :  `numeric` to `as.numeric`, else the error message `argument 'length' incorrect`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think this might be an "oversight" in **chron** (or possibly `data.frame`, but that seems unlikely).

The issue occurs when constructing the data frame in `melt.data.frame` in **reshape2**, which typically uses recycling, but that portion of `data.frame`:

```
for (j in seq_along(xi)) {
    xi1 <- xi[[j]]
    if (is.vector(xi1) || is.factor(xi1)) 
        xi[[j]] <- rep(xi1, length.out = nr)
    else if (is.character(xi1) && class(xi1) == "AsIs") 
        xi[[j]] <- structure(rep(xi1, length.out = nr), class = class(xi1))
    else if (inherits(xi1, "Date") || inherits(xi1, "POSIXct")) 
        xi[[j]] <- rep(xi1, length.out = nr)
    else {
        fixed <- FALSE
        break
    }
```

seems to go wrong, as the chron variable doesn't inherit either Date or POSIXct. This removes the error but alters the date times:

```
x = data.frame(Index = as.chron(c(15657.00,15657.17)), Var1 = c(1,2), Var2 = c(9,8))
class(x$Index) <- c(class(x$Index),'POSIXct')
y = melt(x,id.vars="Index")
```

Like I said, this sorta smells like a bug *somewhere*. My money would be on the need for **chron** to add POSIXct to the class vector, but I could be wrong. The obvious alternative would be to use POSIXct date times instead.

Comment: Indeed, it gives no error messsage, but does not fix it. The dates have changed : `(11/13/12 00:00:00)` -> `"1970-01-01 05:20:57 CET"`

Comment: If you accept the fact that  data frames have the odd behavior of recycling some classes but not others then the problem is in reshape2 for assuming otherwise. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641538/melt-with-chron/15642452#15642452

Comment: @fRed So maybe the most expedient thing to do would be to use POSIXct date times, rather than chron?

Comment: That could introduce potential time zone bugs that can't affect chron.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck So we've circled back to this being a bug in reshape2?